# Connecting to wifi

Tags: networking, wifi

I am an absolute beginner with the Raspberry Pi and I try to connect to my WiFi. I see people talking about WiFi adapter but is it possible without a WiFi adapter? I do see the WiFi Config  at my desktop but when I try to add my network, I get

> Failed to enable network in wpa_supplicant configuration

I have to spend money again, just to be able to connect to WiFi? Really no other way? I tried to find the answer on Google but I just get several tutorials on HOW to connect to WiFi and all are with WiFi Adapter.

Comment: Wifi is not something that is implemented purely with software.  If you look for it, you'll notice the operating system on your pi has *software* for printing (as in, on paper).  However, as is, alone, no matter what you do, the pi will not print anything on paper for obvious reasons -- it's missing some *hardware*.  But if you plug a printer into it, suddenly the software becomes useful! Wifi is the same, but since the hardware is smaller than a printer, it is often built (but not always!) built into modern devices.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a related question on the [Raspberry Pi FAQ's](http://www.raspberrypi.org/faqs):

> ### Will there be a WiFi option?
>
> Not in the first version, though you can add a dongle. ARM Linux WiFi
>   support can be a bit patchy; there’s a list of tested dongles on the
>   wiki.

For a list of Raspberry Pi supported adapters, look at the [Raspberry Pi wiki for verified USB wifi adapters](http://elinux.org/RPi_USB_Wi-Fi_Adapters).  I would put the list in this answer, but it is too extensive.  If you scan through them you can easily find a cheap one.

Comment: Ok so I am thinking about buying the TL-WN321G, but it needs an usb port but I also need a mouse and keyboard. So that means I have to use a wireless mouse? Or use a USB hub?

Comment: @loko Look into a powered USB hub.

Comment: Thank you very much + will this one work on all OS and without powered usb? http://www.alternate.nl/html/search.html?query=TL-WN725N&x=0&y=0

Comment: @loko The Raspberry Pi Wiki says it will work.

Answer (score 1):

The Raspberry PI model B doesn't have a wifi adapter built in.

You need something like this from Adafruit:
http://canada.newark.com/webapp/wcs/stores/servlet/ProductDisplay?catalogId=15003&langId=1&urlRequestType=Base&partNumber=53W6285&storeId=10196

Comment: Is it a MUST HAVE...?

Comment: If you want wifi, yes

Comment: No other way to get wifi?

Comment: @loko Chances are you can get a pi compatible wifi adapter at a store near you for ~$15.  Most, *but not all* of them are pi compatible, so before you buy, maybe print this out ;D http://elinux.org/RPi_USB_Wi-Fi_Adapters and bring it with you.  There may even be someone there who knows about linux (it is essentially a linux issue).  Keep your reciept, lol, and beware that you'll need to plug it in before you boot, because plugging it in afterward may kill the power momentarily.

Answer (score 0):

Once you get a Wifi Dongle, you may want to get an active USB hub and plug the Wifu Dongle into the hub. Many users report power issues with too many USB devices or devices that consume a lot of energy (like Wifi Dongles).

The only network device on the RPi Model B is the Ethernet port.